# How to run a file which is located in db folder in rails (version 2.3.18)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on maintenance project which is in rails version '2.3.18'.
And i am able to run the migrations but could not obtain the data.
There is no seeds.rb file in db, but there is a file named example_data.rb as:

```
module FixtureReplacement
  attributes_for :category do |c|
    c.name = "General"
    c.desc = "general"
  end
  attributes_for :price, :from => :equity do |a|
    a.etype = "dollars"
    a.exchange = '60'
  end
 ..........................
.................
end
```

I think this is the seed file for the project. I tried running

rake db:example_data (recollecting rake db:seed), but there is no luck.

Please help me, how to run this file.

Comment: do a research in all the project's files and look for `FixtureReplacement`, you might find a particular file calling this Module and maybe tips on how to run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, that's not a seed file, but a replacement for Rails' built in fixtures called [FixtureReplacement](https://rubygems.org/gems/fixture_replacement) that's intended to be used in your test environment. It's very similar to something like [Fabrication](https://rubygems.org/gems/fabrication) or [FactoryGirl](https://rubygems.org/gems/factory_girl).

That file doesn't actually define any preset data, but instead gives you a cleaner way to create records with preset defaults. You won't be able to simply run the file, but you could write a script that includes your Rails environment and includes `FixtureReplacement`. From there you can run commands to generate data as shown in `FixtureReplacement`'s [documentation](http://replacefixtures.rubyforge.org/):

```
# Require Rails env on this line
include FixtureReplacement
new_category # Uses defaults
new_category(name: "Something", desc: "something")
new_price # Uses defaults
# and so on
```

Honestly though, it might be wiser to just script something from scratch.

Comment: Thanks a lot @faraz. Especially the [documentation](http://replacefixtures.rubyforge.org/) helped me a lot.

Comment: I wish you lot's of luck! You'll need it... Legacy code is always a pain. ;)